# How to spread dynamic divs vertically, evenly?

Tags: html, css

Basically, i want the child divs to spread out evenly in the parent div, and if, one of the child divs is removed, the rest should resize and to fill the remaining space evenly again.

Ex:

```
 ---parent---------------
|  --------------------  |
| |              child | |
|  --------------------  |
|  --------------------  |
| |              child | |
|  --------------------  |
|  --------------------  |
| |              child | |
|  --------------------  |
 ------------------------
```

now when a child div is remove, it should become

```
 ---parent---------------
|  --------------------  |
| |              child | |
| |                    | |
| |                    | |
|  --------------------  |
|  --------------------  |
| |              child | |
| |                    | |
| |                    | |
|  --------------------  |
 ------------------------
```

Now, i want to do this with only pure html/css, but at the moment i can't find a solution.

The two other alternatives i am considering are to:

- calculate the heights using javascript
- create different classes for a bunch of scenarios (eg: a parent with
  2 child divs, 3 child divs, 4 child divs, etc) and then load them
  accordingly with php

Anyone got a better idea ?

Comment: What tool did you use to create the ASCII diagrams ?

Comment: no tools, just the keyboard, designed it myself :))

Comment: Give you a +1 for the ascii art !

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Use [**css tables**](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/tables.html#table-display) with `table-layout: fixed` - no javascript is necessary.

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/danield770/G4dDR/2/)**

To see this working click 'inspect element' on one of the li elements of the above fiddle, then right-click 'delete node' and voila! - exactly what you need.

### Markup

```
<ul>
    <li><span>Item1</span></li>
    <li><span>Item1</span></li>
    <li><span>Item1</span></li>
    <li><span>Item1</span></li>
</ul>
```

### CSS

```
ul
{
    display: table;
    table-layout: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    border: 1px solid #c2c2c2;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

li
{
    text-align: center;
    display: table-row;
    background: pink;
}
span
{
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
    border-top: 1px solid green;
}
```

Comment: This is so cool and simple, thank you for helping me out. But apparently i need to go and read the display tag specs, as i've missed this completly

Comment: @RaulGlogovetan, glad it helped. I also added a link to the w3c documentation of css tables

Comment: Unfortunately, this only works if the content of each row is the same height. If the text on one row wraps and the other rows don't, then one that wraps will end up being taller. Essentially, only the vertical padding is the same on each row. Here's the fiddle demonstration: http://jsfiddle.net/7zfdhftt/

Answer (score 5):

If anyone is willing to use CSS3, then flexbox layout is also a good solution!

```
.parent{
  height:200px;
  width:100%;
  display:flex;
  flex-direction:column;
}
.child{
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
}
```

[Updated JSFiddle Link](http://jsfiddle.net/RsD2G/143/)

Answer (score 2):

I have used `display:table` and `display:table-row` properties.

[Here is the fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/RsD2G/)

Answer (score 1):

## Flexbox (yay)

Say you have a bunch of `items` and they live in the `parentContainer`. If the `parentContainer` lives inside another container (`grandParentContainer`?) you need to make sure that `parentContainer` is taking up the full size it can (trap for young players).

So lets say `grandParentContainer` is taking up the entire window. Then we should give `parentContainer` the css style like this:

```
.parentContainer {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
```

See the [best flexbox guide on the internet](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) for other `justify-content` options.

Height and width then take up 100% of the super container (`grandParentContainer`). We describe the container as a flexbox and give the direction column so it stacks its children vertically.

Then maybe give the children a margin of `1rem` or something so it looks half decent.

```
.item {
  margin: 1rem;
}
```